# d3 make a force-directed-tree layout into a circle shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

How do you make a force-directed-tree layout into a circle shape

[D3.js Titles on Collapsible Force-Directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747638/d3-js-titles-on-collapsible-force-directed-graph)

instead of hanging?

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500

Found an unanswered similar question here: [D3.js how do I arrange nodes of a force layout to be on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439832/d3-js-how-do-i-arrange-nodes-of-a-force-layout-to-be-on-a-circle)

Apparently it can be done as seen in the second link. Just no idea how. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `charge()` function to specify how repellant each node is each other. The more negative the number, the more they will repel each other. For example, try -250 or -500.

One side-effect of increasing the charge is the initial layout is more "bouncy" since the nodes are applying more force on each other.

Comment: `charge()` did it, thanks. Also seems [`size()` has some say in it too](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#size). If you remove `size()` from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xnwyzj6q/2/) (Line 12) it all "falls" to one side.