# Nodes Title around a Circle

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I created a force layout around a circle in d3js ([D3.js how do I arrange nodes of a force layout to be on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439832/d3-js-how-do-i-arrange-nodes-of-a-force-layout-to-be-on-a-circle)) and now I want to put the labels around like this:

[image]

but right now this is what I'm getting:
You can take a look here too: https://bl.ocks.org/pierreee1/07eb3b07ba876011419168d60c587090

[image]

What could I do to get the results I want? I searched some questions but none of the solutions have helped me.

Here's my code:

```
// width y height
var w = 1350;
var h = 600;

// declarar la fuerza y la union de los nodos por id, ahora sin charge ni centro porque no se van a correr
var fuerza = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d){
        return d.id;
    }))
;

// insertar los datos y ponerlos en consola
d3.json("actores_v5.json", function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    //verificar los datos
    console.log("Número de Nodos: " + data.nodes.length)
    console.log(data.nodes)
    console.log("Número de Links: " + data.edges.length)
    console.log(data.edges)

    //svg en donde dibujar
    var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
    ;

    //circulo invisible para dibujar los nodos
    // it's actually two arcs so we can use the getPointAtLength() and getTotalLength() methods
    var dim = w/2;
    var circle = svg.append("circle")
        //.attr("d", "M 40, "+(dim/2+40)+" a "+dim/2+","+dim/2+" 0 1,0 "+dim+",0 a "+dim/2+","+dim/2+" 0 1,0 "+dim*-1+",0")
        .attr('cx', w/2)
        .attr('cy', h/2)
        .attr('r', 250)
        .style("fill", "#ffffff")
    ;

    //crea las lineas con un svg y los datos de "edges"
    var lineas = svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(data.edges)
        .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link " + d.tipo; 
            })          
    ;

    //crea los nodos de acuerdo a los nombres
    var nodos = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr('class', function(d){
                if (d.categoria == "gobierno"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }   
                if (d.categoria == "patrimonio"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "planeacion"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "ong"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "gremios"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "academia"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "comunidad"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "privado"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "medios"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
                if (d.categoria == "otros"){
                    return "nodos " + d.categoria;
                }
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseEncima)
            .on("mouseout", mouseAfuera)
            .attr('r', 5)
    ;

    nodos
        .filter(function(d){
            return d.categoria == "gobierno"
                || d.categoria == "patrimonio"
                || d.categoria == "planeacion"
                || d.categoria == "ong"
                || d.categoria == "gremios"
                || d.categoria == "academia" 
                || d.categoria == "comunidad"
                || d.categoria == "privado"
                || d.categoria == "medios"
                || d.categoria == "otros"
            ;
        })
        .style("opacity", 1)
    ;

    //titulos de los nodos
    nodos.append("title")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.id;
        })
    ;

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .attr('class', "text")
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
    ;

    //define los nodos y los links de la simulacion
    fuerza.nodes(data.nodes);
    fuerza.force("link").links(data.edges);

    // calcula los espacios de los circulos en el circulo
    var circleCoord = function(node, index, num_nodes){
        var circumference = circle.node().getTotalLength();
        var pointAtLength = function(l){
            return circle.node().getPointAtLength(l)};
        var sectionLength = (circumference)/num_nodes;
        var position = sectionLength*index+sectionLength/2;
        return pointAtLength(circumference-position)
    }

    // define la posicion de los nodos segun el calculo anterior
    data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
        var coord = circleCoord(d, i, data.nodes.length)
        d.fx = coord.x
        d.fy = coord.y
    });

    for (i = 0; i < data.nodes.length; i++) {
        var angle = (i / (data.nodes.length / 2)) * Math.PI;
        //data.nodes.push({ 'angle': angle });
    }   

    //simulación y actualizacion de la posicion de los nodos en cada "tick"
    fuerza.on("tick", function(){

        lineas.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        });

        nodos.attr("cx", function(d){
                return d.x = d.fx;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d){
                return dy = d.fy;
            })
        ;

        text.attr("x", function(d){
                return dx = d.fx;
            })
            .attr('y', function(d){
                return dy = d.fy;
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
    });

    //saber si las conexiones se ven o no
    var toggle = 0;

    //Create an array logging what is connected to what
    var linkedByIndex = {};
        for (i = 0; i < data.nodes.length; i++) {
            linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
        };

    data.edges.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
    });

    //This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours  
    function neighboring(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }

    function mouseEncima() {

        if (toggle == 0) {

            //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
            d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
            nodos
                .transition()
                .style("opacity", function (o) {
                    return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
                })              
                .attr('r', function(o){
                    return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 10 : 5;
                })
            ;  

            lineas
                .transition()
                .style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
                    return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
                })
            ;

            // text
            //  .transition()
            //  .style("opacity", function (o) {
            //      return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
            //  })
            // ;

            //Reduce the opacity        
            toggle = 1;
        }
    }

    function mouseAfuera() {

            nodos
                .filter(function(d){
                    return d.categoria == "gobierno"
                        || d.categoria == "patrimonio"
                        || d.categoria == "planeacion"
                        || d.categoria == "ong"
                        || d.categoria == "gremios"
                        || d.categoria == "academia" 
                        || d.categoria == "comunidad"
                        || d.categoria == "privado"
                        || d.categoria == "medios"
                        || d.categoria == "otros"
                    ;
                })
                .transition()
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .attr('r', 5)
            ;

            // y las lineas a 0        
            lineas
                .transition()
                .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
            ;

            // text
            //  .transition()
            //  .style("opacity", 0.1)
            // ;

            toggle = 0;
        }   
});
```

Comment: Where is the file: actores_v5.json or a smaller version of the dataset

Comment: @PierrePuentes Instead of asking **us** to download the JSON, why don't **you** prepare a running code, with HTML, JS and the JSON, so we just have to adjust it? You can use Blockbuilder, for instance: http://blockbuilder.org. Click the plus sign at the right-hand side to create the JSON file and the JS file, the HTML you can edit at the starting page.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You are right. give me a sec

Comment: Ok, here it is.https://bl.ocks.org/pierreee1/07eb3b07ba876011419168d60c587090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text is positioned a bit outside the big circle so we can read the first character (`textPosition()`).

Based on the position/angle of the text relative to the circle center you have to rotate it, change the text-anchor (`start`, `end`) and a small baseline shift (`dy`) to make the text centered vertical relative to the colored circle.

For the transparency you don't need the `toggle` variable because the `mouseover` event is only called once for every circle.

Removed the redundancy of adding the circle class, it is identical to the `d.categoria`.

What is the purpose of the large OR compare of `d.categoria` in the `filter()` calls? Is this a test if `d.categoria` is defined?

```
// width y height
var w = 1350;
var h = 800;
var RAD2DEG = 180.0/Math.PI;
var gCircleRadius = 250;
var gSmallCircleRadius = 5;

// declarar la fuerza y la union de los nodos por id, ahora sin charge ni centro porque no se van a correr
var fuerza = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d){
        return d.id;
    }))
;

// insertar los datos y ponerlos en consola
d3.json("actores_v5.json", function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    //verificar los datos
    console.log("Número de Nodos: " + data.nodes.length)
    console.log(data.nodes)
    console.log("Número de Links: " + data.edges.length)
    console.log(data.edges)

    //svg en donde dibujar
    var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
    ;

    //circulo invisible para dibujar los nodos
    // it's actually two arcs so we can use the getPointAtLength() and getTotalLength() methods
    var dim = w/2;

    var circle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr('cx', w/2)
        .attr('cy', h/2)
        .attr('r', gCircleRadius)
        .style("fill", "#ffffff");

    //crea las lineas con un svg y los datos de "edges"
    var lineas = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(data.edges)
        .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                return "link " + d.tipo; 
            });

    //crea los nodos de acuerdo a los nombres
    var nodos = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr('class', function (d) { return "nodos" + (d.categoria ? " " + d.categoria: ""); })
            .on("mouseover", mouseEncima)
            .on("mouseout", mouseAfuera)
            .attr('r', gSmallCircleRadius);

    nodos
        .filter(function(d){
            return d.categoria == "gobierno"
                || d.categoria == "patrimonio"
                || d.categoria == "planeacion"
                || d.categoria == "ong"
                || d.categoria == "gremios"
                || d.categoria == "academia" 
                || d.categoria == "comunidad"
                || d.categoria == "privado"
                || d.categoria == "medios"
                || d.categoria == "otros"
            ;
        })
        .style("opacity", 1)
    ;

    //titulos de los nodos
    nodos.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

    var text = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', "text")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

    //define los nodos y los links de la simulacion
    fuerza.nodes(data.nodes);
    fuerza.force("link").links(data.edges);

    // calcula los espacios de los circulos en el circulo
    var circleCoord = function(node, index, num_nodes){
        var circumference = circle.node().getTotalLength();
        var pointAtLength = function(l){
            return circle.node().getPointAtLength(l)};
        var sectionLength = (circumference)/num_nodes;
        var position = sectionLength*(index+0.5);
        return pointAtLength(circumference-position)
    };

    // define la posicion de los nodos segun el calculo anterior
    data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
        var coord = circleCoord(d, i, data.nodes.length)
        d.fx = coord.x
        d.fy = coord.y
    });

    var radiusScale = (gCircleRadius+1.5*gSmallCircleRadius) / gCircleRadius;
    var textPosition = d => {
        var circX = w*0.5, circY = h*0.5;
        var dX = (d.fx - circX)*radiusScale, dY = (d.fy - circY)*radiusScale;
        return { x: circX + dX, y: circY + dY};
    };
    //simulación y actualizacion de la posicion de los nodos en cada "tick"
    fuerza.on("tick", function(){

        lineas.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        });

        nodos.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x = d.fx; })
             .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y = d.fy; });

        text.each( (d, i, nodes) => {
            var textPos = textPosition(d);
            var angle = Math.atan2(textPos.y-h*0.5, textPos.x-w*0.5)*RAD2DEG;
            d3.select(nodes[i])
            .attr('x', textPos.x)
            .attr('y', textPos.y)
            .attr('dy', (angle>90 || angle<-90) ? "0.3em" : "0.4em")
            .style("text-anchor", (angle>90 || angle<-90) ? "end" : "start")
            .attr("transform", `rotate(${ (angle>90 || angle<-90) ? angle+180 : angle}, ${textPos.x}, ${textPos.y})` );
        });
    });

    //Create an array logging what is connected to what
    var linkedByIndex = {};
        for (i = 0; i < data.nodes.length; i++) {
            linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
        };

    data.edges.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
    });

    //This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours  
    function neighboring(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }

    function mouseEncima() {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        nodos
            .transition()
            .style("opacity", function (o) {
                return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
            })
            .attr('r', function(o){
                return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 2*gSmallCircleRadius : gSmallCircleRadius;
            })
        ;  

        lineas
            .transition()
            .style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
                return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
            })
        ;
    }

    function mouseAfuera() {

        nodos
            .filter(function(d){
                return d.categoria == "gobierno"
                    || d.categoria == "patrimonio"
                    || d.categoria == "planeacion"
                    || d.categoria == "ong"
                    || d.categoria == "gremios"
                    || d.categoria == "academia" 
                    || d.categoria == "comunidad"
                    || d.categoria == "privado"
                    || d.categoria == "medios"
                    || d.categoria == "otros"
                ;
            })
            .transition()
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .attr('r', 5)
        ;

        // y las lineas a 0
        lineas
            .transition()
            .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
        ;
    }
});
```

**Edit**

After a look at the complete fiddle.

Suggestion of a change for the link path. Some paths are following the circumference of the circle. The following prevents this and makes sure all paths start in the direction of the center.

```
lineas.attr("d", function(d) {
  return `M${d.source.x},${d.source.y}Q${w*0.5},${h*0.5} ${d.target.x},${d.target.y}`;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Yes, it's something I did in a old code and I forgot to change it. You can check out the new version here: https://bl.ocks.org/pierreee1/afa24dd63bb06caaa77dae7ae85bdb4f (w| credits for the help!) Thank you again.

Comment: @Pierre: I have a suggestion to change the link paths so you can always see them all.

Comment: how could I do that?

Comment: replace the first line in the `tick()` function where you update the link path. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: It looks and works perfect! Thank you very much. Take a look: https://i.imgur.com/LWOM545.png