# d3.js select connected nodes on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, data-visualization, selectall

I am trying to make the text of all connected nodes' labels bold on mouseover. Trying various procedures as you can see from the comments, but still can't get it working. I am using circular graph based on http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5432087.

What I want is, when I hover with mouse over one node, I want all the connected nodes to get bold. (what I have now is that all connected lines get thicker, but I also want to get the nodes on the end of the lines highlighted - bold)

Here is the corresponding code:

```
function mouseovered(d) {
    console.log("mouseOver");
    //d3.select(this).style("font-weight", 700);
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .filter(function(l) { return l.source.name === d.name || l.target.name === d.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return l.value > 0; })
        //.filter(function(l) { return console.log(l)})
        //.style("font-weight", 700);
        .style("stroke-width", "4px")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .filter(function(l) { return l.source.name != d.name && l.target.name != d.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return l.value > 0; })
        //.filter(function(l) { return console.log(l)})
        //.style("font-weight", 700);
        //.style("stroke-width", "4px")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1);

    linkList = d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        //.filter(function(l) { return l.source.name != d.name && l.target.name != d.name; })
        //.filter(function(l) { return l.source.name === d.name || l.target.name === d.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return if (l.source.name === d.name){return l.target.name} else if(l.target.name === d.name){return l.source.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return console.log("L.SOURCE:", l.source.name, "L.TARGET:", l.target.name); })
        .filter(function(l) { return l.source.name, l.target.name; });
        //console.log(linkList);

    console.log("link:", linkList)

    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".nodeText")
        //.filter(function(l) { return d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link").filter(function(k) {return k.source.name === d.name || k.target.name === d.name ; })})
        //.filter(function(l) { return d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link").filter(function(k) {return k.value > 0 ; })})
        .filter(function(l) { return l.name === "OP PPR_07.1 Posílení výzkumu, technologického rozvoje a inovací"})
        .filter(function(l) { return l.name === linkList})
        .style("font-weight", 700);

}
```

And here is the format of my data:

```
{"nodes": [{"name": "OP PIK_01.1 Rozvoj výzkumu a vývoje pro inovace", "group": 1}, {"name": "OP PIK_01.2 Rozvoj podnikání a konkurenceschopnosti malých a středních podniků", "group": 1}, {"name": "OP PIK_01.3 Účinné nakládání energií, rozvoj energetické infrastruktury a obnovitelných zdrojů energie, podpora zavádění nových technologií v oblasti nakládání energií a druhotných surovin", "group": 1}, {"name": "OP PIK_01.4 Rozvoj vysokorychlostních přístupových sítí k internetu a informačních a komunikačních technologií", "group": 1}, {"name": "OP PIK_01.5 Technická pomoc", "group": 1}, ...

, {"name": "", "group": 2}, {"name": "", "group": 4}, {"name": "", "group": 6}, {"name": "", "group": 8}, {"name": "", "group": 10}, {"name": "", "group": 12}, {"name": "", "group": 14}, {"name": "", "group": 16}

], "links": [{"value": 0.13757455268389662, "target": 1, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.07236842105263158, "target": 2, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.03948896631823461, "target": 3, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 4, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.007836990595611285, "target": 5, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.009244992295839754, "target": 6, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0005341167044999333, "target": 7, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 8, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.06844336765596608, "target": 9, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 10, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0014781966001478197, "target": 11, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 12, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 13, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 14, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 15, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 16, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 17, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 18, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.004398826979472141, "target": 19, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0018248175182481751, "target": 20, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 21, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0022197558268590455, "target": 22, "source": 0}, {"value": 0.0, "target": 23, "source": 0}, ... ]}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but may give you a good direction to go in. You can look at the H for Highlighting section on this page: http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/ . On this page, the example uses double click to call the function connected nodes. The connected nodes function then reduces the opacity of all nodes except for the neighboring nodes. Instead of opacity, you could change that to make the connected nodes bold / increase the size of those nodes. Also call the function on mouseover because you want on mouseover. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Coola thank you for your comment. I looked at the site and think it could help. However I am having an issue, as if you look at the code on which I based mine: http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5432087 The "graph" which I need in the appended code from the highlighting is accessible only within the drawGraph function. I tried to make the whole code afterwards as the drawGraph function, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529999/nodes-title-around-a-circle and the bl.ocks with the complete program https://bl.ocks.org/pierreee1/afa24dd63bb06caaa77dae7ae85bdb4f it contains a link to a SO question regarding highlighting connected nodes

Comment: Please supply a usable data file that shows some nodes and links.

Comment: @JameStitel check rioV8s answer. If it doesn't work, share a block with your code and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the original Miserable nodes and links I found the following code to work.

```
function mouseover(d) {
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .filter(function(l) { return l.source.name === d.name || l.target.name === d.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return l.value > 0; })
        .classed("highlight", true);
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .filter(function(l) { return l.source.name != d.name && l.target.name != d.name; })
        .filter(function(l) { return l.value > 0; })
        .classed("downlight", true);
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
        .each(function(n) {
            for (let index = 0; index < graphData.links.length; index++) {
                const element = graphData.links[index];
                if ( (element.source.name === d.name && element.target.name === n.name) ||
                     (element.target.name === d.name && element.source.name === n.name)
                   ) {
                    d3.select(this).attr("r", 8);
                    return;
                }
            }
         });
}

function mouseout(d) {
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .classed("highlight downlight", false);
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .classed("highlight", false);
}

// Draws nodes with tooltips
function drawNodes(nodes) {
    // used to assign nodes color by group
    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return d.name; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill",   function(d, i) { return color(d.group); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) { addTooltip(d3.select(this)); mouseover(d); })
        .on("mouseout",  function(d, i) { d3.select("#tooltip").remove(); mouseout(); });
}
```

You need a bit of CSS too

```
.node {
    stroke: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node.highlight {
    stroke: #0000;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}

.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #888888;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

.link.highlight {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-opacity: 1.0;
}
.downlight {
    stroke-opacity: 0.1;
}
```

And a save of the graph data

```
var graphData = null;

// Draws an arc diagram for the provided undirected graph
function drawGraph(graph) {
    graphData = graph; // save for later in mouseover

    ....
}
```